# Grafana dashboard doesn’t have a “+” icon on the side menu

Tags: installation, grafana

I have installed Grafana according to the documentation listed in [install Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/debian/). After I succeeded it didn’t look like the one in the documentation. Is there another configuration so that the “+” icon and other icons can appear?.

Environment

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Grafana version: Enterprice 8.6
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logged in as a viewer and don't have the required permissions to create/edit dashboards, use explore or access configuration/server-admin pages.

To fix this, log in with a user that has the required permissions.

Comment: thank you, I just found out that my role is viewer, even though I'm logged in with Github. @Matt